# Create a program for an unsorted linked list that removes duplicate and sort it in ascending order

Tags: java

Create a program for an unsorted linked list that removes duplicate and sort it in ascending order.

```
package fp1;


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in
 * the editor.
 */

public class FP1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int[] C = { 6, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 8, 7, 7, 1, 9 };

        int current = C[0];
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
            if (current == C[i] && !found) {
                found = true;
            } else if (current != C[i]) {
                System.out.print(" " + current);
                current = C[i];
                found = false;

                System.out.print(" " + current);

                int min;
                {
                    // Assume first element is min
                    min = i;
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < C.length; j++) {
                        if (C[j] < C[min]) {
                            min = j;

                        }
                    }
                    if (min != i) {
                        final int temp = C[i];
                        C[i] = C[min];
                        C[min] = temp;
                    }
                    System.out.print(C[i]); // I print the in ascending order
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's error with our program?

Comment: Homework season... Failed to find a linked list here.

Comment: Can you show us your LinkedList code and explain to us why you believe it is not doing the right thing, i.e. what is the simplest example which has a problem.

Comment: Cause here is the output " 6 41 4 22 2 53 5 84 8 77 7 88 8 99" and I don't know how to solve it. It should be in a ascending order and no duplicate number. 

Linked list? That's all our program code.

Answer (score 1):

With Java collections, you can do this in a few lines of code:

```
public static <T> void removeAndSort(List<T> list) {
    Set<T> set = new TreeSet<>(list); // collect distinct elements in sorted order
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(set);
}
```

First, I collect all list items into the `Set` to discard duplicate elements. Then, I remove all elements from original list by `list.clear()` and add elements from `Set` there. As I used `TreeSet`, elements are copied in ascending order.

If you're not restricted to operate on original collection, you can make even simpler:

```
list = list.stream().sorted().distinct().collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer more understandable for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't add/remove things from an array (I think). For that you should use a list or something like that. You can, however, change the elements of the array around.

The method to sort array I am going to use in this example is the [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) method.

```
final int[] C = {6,4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 8, 7, 7, 1, 9};

int t = 0; // This will store a temporary value to do the sorting
boolean sort = false;

while (!end) {              
    end = true;

    //Passing to check, it jumps the already checked indexes
    for (int j = 1; j < C.length; j++) {
        if (C[j-1] > C[j]) {
            //Sets the boolean to false, so it will keep counting
            end = false;
            //Swaping the elements
            t = C[j-1];
            C[j-1] = C[j];
            C[j] = t;
        }
    }
}

// Your array is now sorted in ascending order
// To print it, without repeating, you should do something like this:
for (int k = 0; k < C.length - 1; k++) {
    // It is sorted, so if the subsequent elements are not the same, they do not repeat!
    if (C[k] != C[k + 1]) {    // It checks if the next one is different
        System.out.println(C[k]);    // If isn't, prints
    }
}
```

Hope it helped you.